# Why is the navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem not showing up on the left?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have set up a navigationBar and I'm trying to add a PNG to the left as a leftBarButtonItem but it's showing up in the middle of the navigationBar.

```
private func configureNavBar() {
    var image = UIImage(named: "netflixLogo") // PNG
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: nil) This didn't work either.
    
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    
    //These buttons are working, they are on the right side.
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "play.rectangle"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil),
    ]
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
}
```

This is what I see on the simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's on the left, but the image is just too wide and tall for the nav bar so is displayed aspect fitted in the center of its bounds

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.

Try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeTo(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        }
        
        return image.withRenderingMode(self.renderingMode)
    }
}
```